# Any experiences with xp-dev.com?

Tags: svn

I know there are a number of threads recommending [xp-dev.com](http://xp-dev.com), but I'm wondering if anyone has had any reason not to recommend the service?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have used xp-dev for a few months now and have no complaints so far.

Answer (score 2):

I just signed up with them a few weeks ago, and now today the service is down.  This is unacceptable for me.  I can understand, but not be happy about occasional blips, but so far it has been down all morning which is more than a blip.  no service, nor work gets done.  I am halfway tempted to go back to racking my own servers in a datacenter.  It never pays to try and save money.

And it's not just the service, the entire website is down, which means I can't even get their phone number to call them (I am a paying customer, not just using the free service).

Comment: Yeah, and there are no notifications anywhere. The svn web interface seems to be working, though, but that's all.

Comment: @talonx: Bit of an old thread, but I use xp-dev all the time and find its great most of the time. Only downside is the occassional down-time, would be nice if they sent an email around or some form of notification. However, I have noticed now that they tend to post it on twitter (http://twitter.com/xpdev) if they intend to carry out any maintenance.

Answer (score 1):

No reason for that :) It's simply amazing.

I would say: try it!

Answer (score 1):

I've just started using xp-dev 1 month or so before and has gone down once before for about 2-3 days and is down right now!

Answer (score 1):

It has gone down previously and it is down now(right when I need to commit). You might be better going elsewhere. Me and my team have had better luck with a company called BeanstalkApp and with Google Code.

Answer (score 1):

almost a year using it.  Works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

I've been using their free service for about 2 years and never had any issues at all.  I just started paying for a subscription because I wanted the regular backups.

The only downside is that the web interface is really ugly with adverts on the free version- but it *is* free.

I would recommend!